# classifying a set of images

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

in my dataset, each sample is a set of images.
some samples are a set of just one image, and some samples have upto 10 images.
I have labelled each sample (set of images --> label), and would like to train a classifier

example: 
sample i is a set of n(i) pictures of person p(i) 
each sample is labeled with how attractive person p(i) is.

what is the simplest keras image classification code example that instead of classifying one image, the network can classify a set of variable size of images?

Comment: Please clarify this, Each sample in one set have same label or complete set represent one label? Are samples in one set correlated?

Comment: Completen set (1-10 images) receives one label. Images in a set are highly correlated I.e. they are all pictures of the same kitchen from different angles.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `ConvLSTM`, which keeps the `spatial` as well as the `temporal` relation between `sequence of images`. In keras, there is no official implementation, but there is [this-thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/401), which have lots of ideas and implementation.

There is a [repo](https://github.com/anayebi/keras-extra), which provide a custom `conv-lstm` layer. Also, tensorflow has stable implementation of this.

For different sequence lengh, you can add a image with zero value. As long as this is a sequence, it doesn't matter/effect the model.